# ios: image resize as per screen resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I am displaying image thumbnails from urls(which are in json file) into custom cells of a tableview.

The images loaded from url are not showing up properly- they are of a resolution much higher than need and some are of much lower resolution.

How do I manipulate these images so that they are scaled properly as per each screen(retina as well as normal) in iphone?

How do I scale and resize the thumbnail images from url?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you care about other issues like memory or disk usage (for some caching) for the images, you don't have to resize them.

You can use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` as `contentMode` for an `UIImageView` and just set an image for the image view. It would be sufficient for you.